# Why can't I retrieve float column using select query

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio, datatable

This is my database table:
[image]

This is the structure of my database table:

[image]

I use the following query to retrieve the row with 'slNo' 4 and store it in a `DataTable`:

```
    MySqlDataAdapter mysqlDataAdapter = new MySqlDataAdapter("select daybookDate, voucherNo, accountItem, debit, credit, narration from daybooktable where slNo ='4'", con)
    nonDetailedDaybookList = new System.Data.DataTable();
    mysqlDataAdapter.Fill(nonDetailedDaybookList);
    mysqlDataAdapter.Dispose();
```

But, when I display this datatable, only the 'debit' and 'credit' column appears to be null. I don't know why.

Comment: Have you tried the query in mysql alone?

Comment: Yes.. then it retrieves the row in the right way... credit and debit is not null when I run the query on mysql

Comment: Could you show us how `debit` and `credit` are inserted?